# How to access the data in the button Clicked row in grid(that is dynamically bound by jquery)using javascript?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
function updateGrid(data) { // appending the retrieved data(user details) to the grid
        var i = 0;
        var content;
        $("#GridView1").html('');
        $("#GridView1").append("<tr><th>" + "Name" + "</th><th>" + "Gender" + "</th><th>" + "Date of Birth" + "</th><th>" + "Role" + "</th><th>" + "Password" + "</th><th>" + "Email" + "</th><th>" + "Edit" + "</th></tr>");
        while (data[i] != null)
        {
            $("#GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + data[i].gender + "</td><td>" + data[i].dob + "</td><td>" + data[i].role + "</td><td>" + data[i].password + "</td><td>" + data[i].email + "</td><td>" + "<button id=btnEdit  onclick='test()'>Edit</button>" + "</td></tr>");// HERE I M DYNAMICALLY CREATING A BUTTON IN THE LAST. WHEN I CLICK IT IT CALLS TEST().HOW CAN I SEND THE DATA IN THIS ROW TO THAT TEST() FUNCTION IN ORDER TO ACCES THEM
            i++;
        }
    }
    function test() {

        alert('edit button is clicked');
        // I NEED TO ACCESS THE ROW'S DATA WHERE THIS EDIT BUTTON IS CLICKED.
    }
```

This is my code. Using jquery ajax i am getting data from the db and dynamicaaly adding to the grid, and also i m creating an edit button in the end of the row. I am calling the method test() on buttonclick. How to send the values of the current row to that test() funcation or how can i access them in the test() function...

Comment: Have a look at the on() function using the delegation method - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
$("#GridView1").append("<tr id="+data[i]+"><td>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + data[i].gender + "</td><td>" + data[i].dob + "</td><td>" + data[i].role + "</td><td>" + data[i].password + "</td><td>" + data[i].email + "</td><td>" + "<button id=btnEdit  onclick='test("+data[i].Id+")'>Edit</button>" + "</td></tr>");

function test(id) {

    Here use jquery selector to access the <tr> by id, then you can operate with the data in it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the Edit button a class, then use jquery to access that class and its parent to get the data

```
"<button id=btnEdit class='edit'>Edit</button>"

$('.edit').click(function(e){ // pass in e to find the button clicked

    var row = $(e.target).parents('tr'); // or var row = $(e.target).parent().parent();



});
```

This will minimise the use of the same ID

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried it but this classname.click function is not happening. when i use normal javascript funtion in the onclick even of the button, it is getting called.. but the problem is how to access the data.